# SELECT statement for getting counts in table

Tags: sql, select

I have a table "downloads" with the following information:

```
objKey     CustNum    UserId    DownloadDate
51048879   123        7654       2014-09-01
51048879   234        32434      2014-09-02
51048879   123        7654       2014-09-01
51047379   2132       3456       2014-08-20
51048879   2132       9786       2014-09-01
51047379   123        7654       2014-09-02
```

I want to get counts by downloadDate of how many products, customers, and users downloaded. So I would want:

```
DownloadDate      Products       Customers    Users
2014-09-01         1              2            2
2014-09-02         2              2            2
2014-08-20         1              1            1
```

Can someone help me with the SELECT statement? Each time I have tried I get incorrect numbers. I would think this should be easier than what I tried.

Comment: They key here is you can use distinct within a count to get unique values.

Answer (score 5):

```
select downloaddate,
       count(distinct objkey) as products,
       count(distinct custnum) as customers,
       count(distinct userid) as users
from downloads
group by downloaddate
```

Answer (score 5):

You want `count(distinct)`.  I think this does what you want:

```
select DownloadDate, count(distinct objKey) as Products,
       count(distinct CustNum) as Customers,
       count(distinct UserId) as Users
from table t
group by DownloadDate
order by DownloadDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it:

```
select DownloadDate, count(disinct objKey) as products, count(distinct CustNum) as customers, count(distinct UserId) as users
from downloads
group by DownloadDate
order by DownloadDate
```

Comment: I have another Select that is a little similar. The file has custNumb, projNum, and a status in each record. There can be multiple records per customer.  I would like to get custNum, count of status = 'Live', count of status = 'Identification', count of total projects. Some counts can be zero. I tried a SELECT similar to the ones provided above with the distinct but they didn't produce the right results. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to study a little SQL.  You can't get this done by asking here.